# How can I fix the error "Undefined array key 1" on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I run `php artisan serve` command I get the following errors

```
PHP 8.1.5
Composer version 2.4.2
Laravel Framework 9.31.0

   WARN  [F.


   ErrorException

  Undefined array key 1

  at C:\OpenServer\domains\chorva\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:308
    304▕             : '/^\[([^\]]+)\]/';
    305▕
    306▕         preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
    307▕
  ➜ 308▕         return Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1]);
    309▕     }
    310▕
    311▕     /**
    312▕      * Get the request port from the given PHP server output.

  1   C:\OpenServer\domains\chorva\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:308
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}()

  2   C:\OpenServer\domains\chorva\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:254
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::getDateFromLine()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There have been changes to this file in the Laravel core just 4 days ago. I suspect you are experiencing problems in that regard.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/f40fe7d303544a66f7bcbee8e25c96c743d64d1a

I would try to downgrade the Laravel version a bit and see if it resolves your issue.
If it does you should open a issue on the Laravel github page.

Comment: I opened an issue on the Laraval github page (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/44282)

Comment: Did you confirm that it worked if you downgraded laravel locally first?

Answer (score 0):

Update function in ServerCommand.php line no :300

file location :- laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServerCommand.php

```
protected function getDateFromLine($line)
    {
        $regex = env('PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS', 1) > 1
            ? '/^\[\d+]\s\[(.*)]/'
            : '/^\[([^\]]+)\]/';

        preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);

        if (isset($matches[1])) {  
         return Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1]);
        }
         return Carbon::now(); 
    }
```